# How to cache authentication in a python API

Tags: python, dependencies

Our python Api has a structure where consumers will call our main api which will call many apis internally to get data. Since we are calling around 5-8 apis internally depending on the consumer needs, the response time is more than 1 second. We verified the flow and figured out that the authentication step in each internal api is taking longer time and hence bumping up the response time. Do we have any dependencies we can add to cache the authentication so that we dont need to authenticate for each internal api?

Comment: i dont understand you question? normally you authenticate and get a refresh and access token ... use the access token for up to XXX minutes and then you need to refresh the token or reauth... in othercases you have an api token that lives until you destroy it ... there is no way to answer this question with the info you have provided.... if they are internal api's you could get rid of authentication all together and just only allow specific  urls to access it .. .etc

Comment: I am using ldap authentication for internal apis so if i can cache the authentication call details for 2-3 min for atleast a whole flow it will be good. Curently the authentication is happening multiple time in a single flow

Comment: that seems like the wrong auth choice ... i think the only way you can bypass auth there is to maintain the connection ... which i doubt you can do with more than 1 user at a time (not positive) ... can you change your auth? ie import users from ldap and authenticate once against ldap and then generate an internal token or something that just skips the ldap auth

Comment: Main issue is our firm needs some type of auth check to be done even if its an internal api. There was a suggestion to use something similar to asynctaskexecutor in java which can keep the authentication live for XX minutes. But i am not sure whether we have any thing similar to that in python.

Comment: i think if you use asgi and websockets you might be able to "keep a connection alive" ... I didnt say no auth is the right choice... I just said straight up ldap is unlikely the right choice (I know it was a tempting choice since "it just works", and your company already uses it) (importing users and synching periodically... as well authenticating the user via ldap on the start of each user session would probably be plenty sufficient and you would have alot more flexibility)

Comment: You can use a rich token that can be verified by the services like a JWT.